# Obtaining Data From Repeater asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am an amateur as far as **asp.net** is concerned. What I'm trying to do is that I have a repeater control in my page that is set to show data upon selection of an item in a radio button list.

Upto this point its all good, next what I have to do is: I want a book now button for each repeater item which I can do as well.

But the question is: after user clicks book now how do I know which repeater item user has clicked? And how do I get the h_id(unique id of the table that repeater shows data of) of that item so that I can do further operations.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a button or link in the repeater which an Eval("ID") as its commandargument and then use that value on postback - ala http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Repeater-Get-Item-ItemIndex-CommandName-and-CommandArgument-on-Click-Events.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your hlp mate. But what i was asking was i want to retrieve not the id of the repeater but one field(h_id in my case) that the repeater displays from database.